# How does a script prefaced with #!/bin/rm delete itself?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I was reading [Chapter 2 of the Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/sha-bang.html) where I read about this script in a [footnote](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/sha-bang.html#FTN.AEN240):

```
#!/bin/rm
# Self-deleting script.

# Nothing much seems to happen when you run this... except that the file disappears.

WHATEVER=85

echo "This line will never print (betcha!)."

exit $WHATEVER  # Doesn't matter. The script will not exit here.
                # Try an echo $? after script termination.
                # You'll get a 0, not a 85.
```

Usually `rm` takes an argument and deletes that file. Here, `rm` somehow knows to act upon the script it's executing. Does that mean that when a shell encounters the `#!`, it passes the (fully qualified?) path to that file as the argument to the program specified after `#!`?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose the name of your script file is `foo`, and it begins with the shebang:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

It's as if when you run the script, it's like you run it like:

```
/bin/sh foo
```

In your example, the shebang is:

```
#!/bin/rm
```

So it's as if run the script like:

```
/bin/rm foo
```

which in result deletes itself.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you're exactly right when you say "it passes the (fully qualified?) path to that file as the argument to the program specified after #!".

This is why shell scripts start with `#!/bin/sh` or similar, and Python scripts start with something like `#!/usr/local/bin/python`.

The "shebang" line is intended to run an interpreter for scripts, but any executable can be specified.

Answer (score 2):

When a script contains a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) and is executed by saying:

```
./path/to/script
```

the program loader is instructed to run the path specified in the shebang line with the path to script as an argument.

In your case, the script contains `#!/bin/rm` as the first line, and executing it by saying

```
./selfdeletingscript.sh
```

would cause the following to be executed:

```
/bin/rm ./selfdeletingscript.sh
```

---

Additionally, you might have observed that executing your script by saying:

```
/bin/sh ./selfdeletingscript.sh
```

or

```
bash ./selfdeletingscript.sh
```

would **not** delete it because you've *specified* the path to the interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, bash executes the the script as

```
/bin/rm <Name of script file> [Optional arguments]
```

From bash man page

> If the program is a file beginning with #!, the remainder of the first
>   line specifies an interpreter for the program.
>          The shell executes the specified interpreter on operating systems that do not handle  this  executable  format  them‐
>          selves.  The arguments to the interpreter consist of a single optional argument following the interpreter name on the
>          first line of the program, followed by the name of the program, followed by the command arguments, if any.

Comment: On just about any Unix-like system, the `#!` is handled by the kernel, not by the shell.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Thanks for that! That was actually at the (unfortunately unstated) heart of my question. So the shell passes control to `file` and then to the kernel?

Comment: @KeithThompson can you explain it? When you are typing a command in bash for sh compatible interpreter, the bash parses the file's first line for #! to find any other interpreter is required to execute the file. Please see "COMMAD EXECUTION" section in bash man page for details how bash executes a command.